# Do plants grow back?

Tags: rage

As one of the loading-screen tips state, searching the wasteland can yield some rare and useful plants, such as the *Night Blossom* or the *Comet Bloom*.

Unlike other crafting components, I have never seen any of these plants for sale at any of the merchants, making the items you can produce with them quite invaluable.

Is that really the case, or do plants actually grow back where you pick them after a period of time? Or perhaps there is a merchant selling plants that I simply haven't gotten to yet?

Comment: What game? I suppose fallout, but still. What game

Comment: @1ntello the game is "Rage", as indicated by the tags on the question. ♪

Comment: @RavenDreamer maybe 1ntello thought the OP was getting angry at the plants not growing back ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Night Blossoms seem to be the only plant that grows back. I've been to Crazy Joe's (I keep wanting to say [Crazy Dave](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Crazy_Dave)) swamp a few times and the Night Blossoms have reset. Comet Bloom and Desert Spores must be found, and I have seen no evidence that they regrow.

I don't know if the Night Blossom's regrowth is due to a timer (real world or in game) or tied to story completion. However, it doesn't really matter as Night Blossoms are the only plant you can purchase (in Subway Town) in the game.

Comment: Answer tick for thoroughness, +1 for crazy Dave.

Comment: Comet Bloom's grow back - there's one outside the Ghosts' hotel I picked about 5 times. Only Desert Spoors don't because then you could give yourself too much permanent health.

Answer (score 1):

Some plants do not grow back. This is most likely due to the fact that they can be used to

> engineer an item that permanently increases your maximum health

later in the game.

Comment: That reason precisely is why I assumed they would not grow back. How long has it been in-game since you picked the plant you base your answer on? Or perhaps you are basing it on something else?

Answer (score 1):

Comet Bloom and Night Blossom appear to randomly respawn when you reload the area. I found you can regularly find Comet Bloom outside the Ghosts' hotel near where you start and Night Blossom in Crazy Joe's swamp.

Both are used in recipes that last 60-90 seconds, so I guess they should be replenishable.

Desert Spoors are only used in that one that permanently increases your health, so don't respawn.

Answer (score 1):

I picked desert spore the very first time I visited Crazy Joe's swamp in the first few hours of play. I am over a day into it game wise and I keep going back to the swamp and checking and still I notice that the spores have still not grown back. I check outside wellspring and also a few other places along the path of my travels where I have picked the spores and nothing so far.

I think that it seems to stand to reason that they do not grow back due to their use - since you can use them to

> create a drug that **permanently** raises your health

I think its safe to say that what you get is it.